# Assigning an alias to a the values in a column (according to their ranking and partitioned by another column) in SQL (Snowflake)?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[image: Sample Data]

I want to anonymize the locations and thus assign them a letter as an alias. So, 1 would correspond with A, 2 with B etc... It's already partitioned by vehicle, so locations can appear multiple times.
Any idea how to do this on SQL (Snowflake)?

Comment: And you expect to have fewer than 26? `chr(64 + dense_rank() over (order by vehicle, location))`?

Comment: Yes... Thank you. Will test this now.

Comment: It works but it's the wrong way round. In my actual data-set, A corresponds with the lowest rank location when I run this. Do you know how to flip this?

Comment: `order by X desc` I noticed that they seemed backward except Salem and Sugarland still don't make sense.

Comment: Thanks so much. all works now.